# How to get data json from 9GAG

Tags: json

maybe you think it's a silly question but I hope you can give me some advises.

My problem: When I view source of 9gag.com, I realize that they have a some lines code to load more content:

```
<div class="loading">
    <a class="btn badge-load-more-post" href="/?id=ag0jnqK%2CaNoj2Nv%2CaEGZb39&c=10" data-loading-text="Loading more posts..." data-load-count-max="30">Load more posts</a>
</div>
```

Then, I try to get data by using PHP-CURL from 
**http://9gag.com/?id=ag0jnqK%2CaNoj2Nv%2CaEGZb39&c=10**, 
I hope I can get data application/json but it return is a text/html ( full html).

I tried to use Network Inspector of Google Chrome, I realize that the data return when Chrome get from link **http://9gag.com/?id=ag0jnqK%2CaNoj2Nv%2CaEGZb39&c=10**

It is possible IF there is a way to help me get data application/json above like Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

9gag **supports** JSON requests !
There is an example of URL : https://9gag.com/v1/tag-posts/tag/samantha/type/fresh

The only thing you have to do is to specify a User-Agent called **Mediapartners-Google** that you can find at https://9gag.com/robots.txt to bypass the Cloudflare captcha.

EDIT : It seems that 9gag removed their Cloudflare protection from their API, so you may not have to get a specific user agent. It a guess, but if you ge tin trouble, you still can do the user agent method.

Comment: the url u gave still works but can u give an example url that returns the hot section of 9gag ? like  https://9gag.com/v1/posts/type/hot

Comment: Sure, there you go : https://9gag.com/v1/group-posts/group/default/type/hot

You can pass some URL parameters : ?after=AFTER&c=COUNTER

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have JSON, you could use this API called infinigag. http://www.programmableweb.com/api/infinigag http://infinigag.com/

But you could also try to parse the html and use that. I think you would be better of parsing the html. Infinigag is more like a user of 9gag. It doesn't contain everything. And if you parse the html you are 100% sure its up to date and you can access everything.

Comment: Because I think HTML not stable than JSON, HTML maybe will be changed in next 1 or 2 months and HTML is really hard parse than JSON. Hi

Comment: You're right you should take a look at that API I gave you. Maybe it covers everything you need. 9GAG doesn't use JSON and I don't know any alternatives.

Comment: The fact is that you're using a "proxy" website, and if this one dies, you won't be able to scrap anymore. That's not an HTML stability issue, but a website stability issue. Use the JSON 9gag URL routes sounds better.