# Accessing an element for scraping data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I want to access the highlighted element. This is part of the html to access the sub comments section in 9gag website. I'm using this meme https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O as an example input for the program.

[image]

I used the following code to access but it doesn't work.

```
sub_com_html = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '//*/div/section/section[2]').Get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

Edit:
I'm able to access the section now and print some subcomments. Thanks to @Arundeep Chohan for correcting my silly mistake. But there's an issue. It’s accessing the sub comments section but its repeating the sub comments for different main comments. This screenshot is part of the output with main comment and sub comments as list. You can see that it’s repeating same data which is wrong. It's also giving the sub comments for only a few of the comments and skipping the rest. Theoretically it should work fine but I don't understand what's going wrong here.

[image]

This is the whole code I'm working with now. The goal is to scrape all the comments and sub comments of a meme.

```
import csv
from email.mime import image
from re import T
from tkinter import SCROLL, Image
from unittest import result

import instanceof as instanceof
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver as uc


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options()
    # options.headless = True
    driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O")
    time.sleep(5)

    # click on I accept cookies
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    try:
        consent_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="qc-cmp2-ui"]/div[2]/div/button[2]')
        actions.move_to_element(consent_button).click().perform()
    except:
        pass

    for i in range(31):
        actions.click()
        actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
    time.sleep(4)

    # click on fresh comments section
    fresh_comments = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/section[2]/section/header/div/button[2]')
    actions.move_to_element(fresh_comments).click(on_element=fresh_comments).perform()
    time.sleep(5)

    # click on lood more comments button to load all the comments
    fresh_comments = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.comment-list__load-more')
    actions.move_to_element(fresh_comments).click(on_element=fresh_comments).perform()

    miN = 1000
    results = []
    comments = {}
    while miN <= 20000:
        window = 'window.scrollTo(0,' + str(miN) + ')'
        driver.execute_script(window)
        time.sleep(3)

        # Dealing with all comments
        try:
            # Scrape the main comments
            try:
                All_comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view")
            except:
                All_comments = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.vue-recycle-scroller__item-view")

            del_comm_cnt = 1
            for item in All_comments:
                try:
                    html = item.get_attribute("innerHTML")
                    if "comment-list-item__text" in html:
                        comment = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.comment-list-item__text").text
                    elif "comment-list-item__deleted-text" in html:
                        comment = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.comment-list-item__deleted-text").text
                        comment = comment + str(del_comm_cnt)
                        del_comm_cnt += 1
                    if(comments.get(comment) == None):
                        sub_coms_list = []
                        comments[comment] = ""

                        # get sub comments
                        if "comment-list-item__replies" in html:
                            # item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.comment-list-item__replies").click()
                            sub_comments = item.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.comment-list-item__replies")
                            actions.move_to_element(sub_comments).click(on_element=sub_comments).perform()
                            sub_com_section = item.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*/div/section/section[2]')
                            sub_com_html = sub_com_section.get_attribute("innerHTML")

                            #sub_coms = sub_com_section.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.comment-list-item__wrapper comment-list-item__wrapper_reply")
                            sub_coms = sub_com_section.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.comment-list-item__text")

                            for com in sub_coms:
                                sub_coms_list.append(com.text)
                            comments[comment] = sub_coms_list

                except:
                    pass

        except:
            pass
        miN = miN + 1500
    driver.quit()

    for i in comments:
        print(i, "\n", comments[i],  "\n\n")
```

Comment: Can you provide the 9gag website please

Comment: https://9gag.com/gag/a5EAv9O I'm using this meme only as a example the program is expected to work for any meme. if you inspect the code of view more replies you can see this section with the highligted code. And every comment with sub comments have the same value in section. So I thought I can scrape all the sub comments if I can get this element.

Comment: Instead of scraping the page have you tried using 9gag API: https://github.com/k3min/infinigag and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27521242/how-to-get-data-json-from-9gag

Comment: What do you want to do? Get all comments for some posts?

Comment: Also it's an xpath instead of css selector.

Comment: @MeT yes. The goal is to get all the comments and sub comments in order for a given meme.

Comment: @dosas I'm doing this project to learn selenium and web scraping so I don't wanna use existing codes or libraries. I wouldn't have an opportunity to think or understand what's happening.